# Sum function returns zero

Tags: google-sheets

I keep getting `0` when summing cells in a column in my Google Spreadsheet:

[image]

[image]

I have verified that the format for both columns are Number:

[image]

If I skip the decimal it works fine:

[image]

Works fine in MS Excel:

[image]

What is going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a `,` (comma) as a delimiter while the spreadsheet expects a `.`(dot)

Mine works with a comma because my language uses a comma as a delimiter.[image]

As you see, my Format -> Number -> Number is different from yours
[image]